# Airflow bash operator: Problem using sed in hdfs

Tags: sed, hdfs, airflow

I have a airflow task that I am trying to use `sed` command for replacing LF with CRLF:

```
hdfs dfs -cat /test/file.txt | sed 's/$/\r/g' | hdfs dfs -put -f - /test/file.txt
```

I get following error:

```
error: sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unterminated `s' command
```

I think it is due to `\r` which it is conflicting with. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason, the `\` is a special character in Python.
To solved it I just added an extra `\` is it becomes `sed 's/$/\\r/g'` , another option is to use prefixing.